# Unable to output cyrillic ASCII encoding

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL field which contains plain text Cyrillic characters (ex. Широка поляна). Collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

When I pull out this content with MySQL query and try to output it with php I always get ???? symbols. HTML encoding is utf8, document encoding is utf8, `mb_detect_encoding()` shows ASCII for the string but none of the PHP / MySQL convert functions turns it into something readable.

Comment: Yet another SET NAMES question... I can't believe one can't get first 200 results from google with the same answer for just `mysql encoding` query

Comment: True, if you know what to look about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely do very common mistake by not setting **connection** encoding. It's usually done in `my.ini` config file, but IMHO the better way is to always enforce this in your code. To do so,  just execute this query:

```
SET NAMES encoding;
```

i.e. for utf8 it would be:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

You do this just after you connect to database and do it once per connection.

Comment: -1 to this one and +1 to other. also, `utf8` is encoding, not collation.

Comment: Oh, so you downvote otherwise valid answer because of wrong word used instead pointing that out or correcting?

Answer (score 3):

For the outdated mysql driver it have to be

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

for mysqli

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

for PDO you have to set encoding in DSN:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set charset for your database connection.
For this reason you can use mysql_set_charset function.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link1);
```

More information: http://php.net/mysql_set_charset

Answer (score 0):

Use in first line of php file

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```